# Is there a way to remove embedded excel functions when importing the data into database using vba recordsets?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am importing excel files one by one into an MS Access database. I only want certain rows read, those which contain data and not ones that contain empty cells with embedded meta-data. For example, some cells inside my excel file appear empty but when I highlight them they have meta-data like: `=IF(K22<>"","hello-world",!Q45,"")`

This meta-data becomes a problem when I iterate the rows through recordsets, it tries to read that meta-data but cannot convert it.

Currently my code iterates a temporary table that is based off the real excel file, then I import that into a MS access database. I have a vba on the back-end that iterates the file through a recordset and then runs some validations, problem is it is also reading in this meta-data and it doesn't know how to convert it. When everything runs it produces a table called `table_name$_ImportErrors`, with a bunch of "Type Conversion Failures".

When I deleted all the empty rows that contained meta-data from the original excel the program runs fine. But in the final version I cannot manually do this.

Is there any way to delete rows that contain that meta-data but not actual data in my script?

Here is a code snippet of my attempted solution:

```
'code that imports the excel file
'then create a temp_table based on main excel
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("temp_table")

while not rs.EOF
    if IsNull(rs.fields("a_null_field_in_same_row_as_meta_data").value) = False Then
    'run data validations here
    else:
        rs.movenext
    end if
wend

'add contents of temp_table into main table inside ms access
```

Here I am trying to skip the rows that contain meta-data on the same rows that contain completely empty cells. The rows whose first cell is empty are also rows that contain meta-data later down the row.

excel file looks like this:

```
field1, field2, field3, field4
------------------------------
sdfsdfs,sdfgsdg,sdgsdg,sdgsdgs
gfsdsfs,gdsgfsg,sdfsgsg,sdfsdf
       ,       ,=IF(..),=IF(..)
       ,       ,=IF(..),=IF(..)
```

Thank you

Comment: And what happens with your attempted solution - error message, wrong result, nothing? Can you not open recordset filtered to exclude all rows where field1 is null or empty string? `SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE Nz(Field1,"") <> "";`

Comment: Is temp_table a link to Excel sheet?

Comment: When I upload the file to be appended to my database the data is appended to the appropriate tables. However, I get two extra tables that appear in my database: ```table$_ImportErrors1``` and ```table$_ImportErrors2```, I suppose I could just drop them after they've loaded. It is just annoying how the embedded meta-data is causing these tables to generate, for some reason it only does this for one of my many files.

Comment: @June7 I am importing the excel files with this line: ```DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "temp_table", Me.txtFileName, True, "Main Information!"``` and once that is loaded I can do ```dbs.execute```.

Comment: So those errors also occur if just setting a link to sheet? I tried your posted formula and it errors as not valid. Why do you have 4 arguments?

Comment: @June7 When I ran ```dbs.execute "SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE Nz(`a field1`,'') <> '';"``` I get the error ```Run-time error '3065': Cannot execute select query```. Also I have to use these dash marks for ```a field``` because the columns headers have spaces in them.

Comment: @June7 the ```DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "temp_table", Me.txtFileName, True, "Main Information!"``` is referring to a hidden sheet named "main information"

Comment: Again, why does your posted formula have 4 arguments? That errors in my Excel. I tested TransferSpreadsheet and import does not error. Cell with valid formula imports calculated result.

Comment: @June7 sorry, this one ```=IF(K22<>"","hello-world",!Q45,"")``` that can be ignored, it's a dummy variable. The original is similar to it. It basically takes a value from the main sheet and maps that value to "Main Information" sheet.

Comment: Why would you post a non-valid formula? Should edit question. So what is special about the one file that errors? Cannot replicate issue so hard to advise solution.

Comment: @June7 Not sure why it is causing conversion errors, but when I delete all rows that are empty in that first field then it works fine, which brings me to the conclusion that its the embedded metadata that is stored there, and also this particular file has more rows than the others which may be throwing things off. I think if I can get that select statement to remove all rows that have an empty first field it should work.

Comment: Why did you use Execute with SELECT statement? Execute is for action SQL (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), not SELECT. Suggestion was for the OpenRecordset method. Put the SQL statement in place of `temp_table`. However, that won't solve issue of import/link worksheet. It is possible to open a recordset with VBA connection to worksheet. No idea if that will still bump against the error because I can't test your worksheet. Unless you want to post question in a forum that allows attaching files and provide it.

Comment: If that worksheet opens fine in Excel, Excel automation should be able to delete rows. The difficulty is figuring out how to identify those rows. Are you sure the first cell is really Null or empty? And you would want to remove all those rows?

Comment: @June7 like this: ```DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SELECT * FROM Main Information WHERE Nz(`a field1`,'') <> '' AS temp_table", Me.txtFileName, True, "Main Information!"``` ?

Comment: @June7 when I highlight the cell of the blank rows nothing shows in the fx window. But if I move to the right a few times I start seeing the fx window with functions like ```=IF(...)```

Comment: No, SQL statement does not work with TransferSpreadsheet. I never suggested changing code for TransferSpreadsheet. I suggested changing recordset code or doing Excel automation. As I said, I tested `=If(...)` function and import worked. So suggest you do a test by deleting just those formulas from cells then see what happens with import. If it still errors then there must be something going on in another cell even though nothing is displayed (non-printing characters can cause a cell/field to be not Null nor empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` gives you an unwanted `*ImportErrors` table, consider a different method to import the spreadsheet data.

You can use an Access query with an appropriate connection string to fetch the spreadsheet data.

Here is an example from my system.  It includes a `WHERE` clause to exclude rows whose first column contains Null.

```sql
SELECT xl.*
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Temp\Sample.xlsx].[Sheet1$] AS xl
WHERE xl.Field1 Is Not Null;
```

If you have trouble constructing the right connection string for your situation, you can temporarily create an Access link to the spreadsheet and then examine the link's properties.

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("Sheet1").Connect
Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Temp\Sample.xlsx

? CurrentDb.TableDefs("Sheet1").SourceTableName
Sheet1$
```

Or if you want to keep the spreadsheet link permanently, your Access query could be even simpler.

```sql
SELECT xl.*
FROM [link name here] AS xl
WHERE xl.Field1 Is Not Null;
```

Either way, once you have a working query, you can use it as the source for `OpenRecordset`, adapt it for a `SELECT ... INTO` query to store its data into a new table, or adapt it as an `INSERT` query to store its data into an existing table.

Comment: This is code I was alluding to in my comment below question. As noted, no idea if the conversion error will still present regardless of filter.

Comment: Thank you is there any other way to use my existing code? I can use dbs.Execute to drop columns but I cant do the same to drop entire rows. Also think I might be confusing empty and null,. I have been using variations of <> "" and IS NOT NULL to delete rows, but nothing seems to be effectively removing those rows that have excel functions in them.

Shouldn't this work?
```dbs.execute "DELETE * FROM temp_table WHERE 'a field' IS NULL"```

.......

@June7 I deleted the rows that look empty but when I click on them they show excel functions, once I did that the file imported successfully.

Comment: Your existing code depends on first using TransferSpreadsheet to import from Excel. That is failing. So, no, your existing code is not adequate and can't just be 'tweaked'. Did you try my suggested test to just remove the formulas from cells?

Comment: Where in my code would this go: ```DELETE FROM temp_table WHERE Len(Nz([a field], '') = 0```?

Comment: Have you tried the answer I offered?  Doesn't the query return only the rows you want?

Comment: If you intend to continue using `TransferSpreadsheet` to import all the rows, and then delete the problem rows, add a new line immediately after `Set db = CurrentDb`  Then copy this highlighted text and paste it into that new line: `db.Execute "DELETE FROM temp_table WHERE Len(Nz([a field], '') = 0", dbfailonerror`

Comment: @HansUp set all that up, I am getting back the error: ```run-time error '3075' Missing ),], or Item in query Expression 'Len(Nz([a field],'') = 0'.```

Comment: My mistake.  It needs one more `)` like this: `db.Execute "DELETE FROM temp_table WHERE Len(Nz([a field], '')) = 0", dbfailonerror`

Comment: Okay, my misunderstanding. Rows are imported, just not data from problem cells. So if you use TransferSpreadsheet still have to deal with the created error tables. I guess a little 'tweak' of your code is possible.

Comment: @HansUp I tried this and still it's producing ```temp_table$_ImportErrors``` if I go into the table it gives the error, field, and row. All the errors read: Type Conversion Failure, and all occur on empty rows that have the embedded functions. I should have noted, this is how I am adding the result to my database: ```dbs.execute "INSERT INTO real_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;"``` then I drop it: ```dbs.execute "DROP TABLE temp_table"```

Comment: @June7 could it be that I am adding to a table that I have already defined the schema (w/data types) for inside my database? real_table represents a table that is per-existing and I am adding that temp_table into.

Comment: @HansUp Is this deleting just that field or the entire row including any embedded meta-data? If delete isn't working is a SELECT statement at all possible here? Id just need to isolate all the rows that have ```len > 0``` at ```[a field]```.

Comment: @onconnext6 `temp_table$_ImportErrors` is created by `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`  and I don't believe there is any way to avoid creating that error table if you're determined to continue using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` with that particular spreadsheet.

Comment: @June7 I was told that if I instead import this as a csv instead of an excel file that the embedded meta-data will not cause import issues - not sure if this is true or not. But do you guys know of a way to instead import or convert this from its current format .xlsx to .csv upon import in code?

Comment: Would have to open workbook and SaveAs csv file. Again, Excel automation could do that.